# Running Firestore local e.g. for testing

Tags: database, firebase, testing, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to run firestore locally (e.g. for **testing** purposes)?

What would the approach to write tests against the DB (except of using mocks)

Answer (score 22):

### Update 2020:

There's now also a [Firebase Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite).

### Update Nov 2018:

Local emulation, at least for the purpose of testing Firestore rules, was demoed [at Firebase Summit 2018](https://youtu.be/pvLkkLjHdkw?t=1098) using [`@firestore/testing`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/testing) and documented under [Test your Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator).

It looks like it's along the lines of:

```
const firebase = require(`@firebase/testing`)
const app = firebase.initializeTestApp({
  projectId: 'my-project',
  auth: { uid: '123', email: 'name@domain.com' }
})

const attempt = app.firestore()
  .collection('colId').doc('docId').get()
firebase.assertFails(attempt)
firebase.assertSucceeds(attempt)
```

It seems early-on, as it's not been noted in the release-notes, but I'm sure it's coming along.

Answer (score 19):

There is not currently, but stay tuned as it's something we want to provide.

In the meantime we suggest uses a separate testing project to cover this. The daily free tier per project helps with this too.

Comment: Found [info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#mocking_database_writes) for unit testing Realtime DB. Looking forward to something similar for Firestore!

Comment: Hi Dan, I am working with at team trying out Firestore. Do you have any ideas of how we could mock data for firestore when doing e2e tests? We are currently using cypress.

Answer (score 8):

You can run the Firestore emulator by running:

`gcloud beta emulators firestore start`

and then set the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable as per the console output (e.g. run `export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=::1:8505`).

This requires the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) and a Java 8+ JRE installed and on your system PATH.

Comment: If you run start without flags it starts on a different port every time. I also couldn't get that to work with the ::1:xxxx. It did work for me when I passed localhost and a fixed port like `gcloud beta emulators firestore start --host-port localhost:8080`

Comment: Gcloud seems to be deprecated these days. I was unable to find the modern way to do this. Any idea how?

Answer (score 2):

for a firestore testing write a js example test.js
you could test write with this format example

```
var data = {
        value: {createTime: new Date(),
                updateTime: new Date(),
                fields:{

                        name:{stringValue:'new value data'},
                        age:{integerValue:50}
                      }
        },
        oldValue: {createTime: new Date(),  //old create time
                updateTime: new Date(),  //old update time time
                fields:{

                        name:{stringValue:'olvalue data'},
                        age:{integerValue:50}
                      }
        }
      };
testFireStoreEvent(data);
```

for run execute

```
firebase experimental:functions:shell < test.js
```

**UPDATE!!!! VALID FOR WRITE AND UPDATE EVENTS**

```
var data = {
    before: {  
          //your before data

    },
    after: {

        //your after data
     }
  };
testFireStoreEvent(data);
```

Comment: a better answer is the one above

Answer (score 1):

There are two libraries which attempt to facilitate mocking of the firebase sdk.

1) https://github.com/soumak77/firebase-mock
2) https://github.com/mikkopaderes/mock-cloud-firestore

I currently use the first one, since it seems to have a bit more of the SDK implemented.

They're not perfect, but they're currently sufficient for my needs, and are preferable to the other approaches since they're entirely in-process.

Note that firebase-mock (#1) does cause a webpack error if used as-is from Webpack/web code. To resolve, you can use option #2 (mock-cloud-firestore), or use the workaround mentioned here (until a fix gets merged): https://github.com/soumak77/firebase-mock/issues/157#issuecomment-545387665

#### Other options:

3) [Firestore emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator): needs the google-cloud-sdk, and relies on a separate process
4) Separate test project: relies on connection to the internet, which also means possible quota limitations/costs
5) [firebase-server](https://github.com/urish/firebase-server): Only supports the realtime-database api, not Firestore

Answer (score 1):

Firestore can be setup in local using `gcloud`.

Start the firestore emulator by running `gcloud beta emulators firestore start --host-port=localhost:8081` and if it started successfully you will be seeing `Dev App Server is now running`

In case if you are using `@google-cloud/firestore` then create the Firestore instance in this way

```
// Firestore instance only for test env
const { Firestore } = require('@google-cloud/firestore')
const instance = new Firestore({ projectId; 'Your project id', host: 'localhost', 'port': 8081})
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you have an option to work with local firestore emulator by setting local host:

```
var db = firebaseApp.firestore();
if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
  db.settings({
    host: "localhost:8080",
    ssl: false
  });
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype#instrument_your_app_to_talk_to_the_emulators